# How can I use the Absolute Path in Spring for my JSP form?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, path

I save these images in my Folder "C:/test" but I can't load them from it beacuse it's outside the project and I NEED an absolute path Location for others PCs.

**This is my Config Class:**

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**").addResourceLocations("file:///./test/");
    }//close addResourceHandlers
```

**This is my JSP:**

```
<img src="<c:url value='C:/test/${employee.documentLinkStr}'/>
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (this work for me).

CONFIG:

```
 @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/yourFolder/**").addResourceLocations("file:///C:/yourFolder/");
}//close addResourceHandlers
```

JSP:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/yourFolder/${employee.documentLinkStr}'/>
```